# Kruskal Wallis test for repeated measures

Tags: repeated-measures, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test

How do you perform the Kruskal Wallis test with 2 repetitions for the same patients?

I have applied it on the difference of scores but what happened if there are more than two repetitions?